# How to send mail using IIS 5.1 in WinXP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, email

I have this code to send mail:

```
public bool SendMail(MailMessage message)
{
    message.From = new MailAddress(AppProperties.FromMailAddress, AppProperties.FromDisplayName);
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient { EnableSsl = AppProperties.EnableSsl };
    try
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and have configured web.config to send mail using IIS 5.1 in localhost with this (as suggested by the answers):

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="localhost"
                 userName=""
                 password=""
                 defaultCredentials="false"
                 port="25" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

What do I have to do to send mail with my IIS 5.1 in Windows XP? Is possible to do it? I guess yes, as you say, since I don't get any exception, but I don't receive it on destination. If I should put an user and a password, wich must be?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: doesn't send anything. Do I have to create an account or something similar in IIS?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't do anything? Do you mean it returns false? If so, please give us the Exception details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first install SMTP server (Windows Components > IIS > SMTP Service) and then configure it to enable relaying.

> IIS > Default SMTP Server > Properties
>   Access > Authentication
>
> Access Control > Anonymous Access - Checked
>
> Relay Restrictions > Relay > Select - Only the list below > Add > 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible, you will no longer need to use SSL however. In the config file, your port will probably be 25, you may or may not need username/password, and of course your hostname will change.

Also make sure you install the SMTP components along with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can send it this way :D (but i think you need to use port 25) smtp class is part of .net